# JBOSS 6.2.0 Parameter count exceeded allowed maximum:512

Tags: jboss

I got below error while using JBOSS 6.2.0 GA. Googled it, found some suggestion for change in standalone.xml(AS7). But for JBOSS 6.2.0 there is no standalone.xml. I tried making changes in standalone-full-ha.xml(standalone/configuration) but it didnt worked out.

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Parameter count exceeded allowed maximum: 512
        org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.addField(Parameters.java:218)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.addParam(Parameters.java:337)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.processParameters(Parameters.java:417)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.processParameters(Parameters.java:368)`enter code here`
        org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:2568)
        org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameterNames(Request.java:1102)
        org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameterNames(RequestFacade.java:371)
        org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.populate(RequestUtils.java:1225)
        org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processPopulate(RequestProcessor.java:821)
        org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:254)
        org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
        org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:525)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
```

Comment: Your request has more than 512 parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try add the following system property to the configuration file (eg standalone.xml).

```
<property name="org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.MAX_COUNT" value="10000"/>
```

or `-Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.MAX_COUNT=10000` in standalone.conf.bat file in bin folder

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Federico. As i am using JBOSS 6.2.0, i dont have standalone.xml inside my jboss directory. 
But changing **properties-service.xml** worked for me.

```
<mbean code="org.jboss.varia.property.SystemPropertiesService" 
         name="jboss:type=Service,name=SystemProperties">
        <attribute name="Properties">
                      org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.MAX_COUNT=10000
        </attribute>
    </mbean>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the solution Federico.

Just a small note. According to JBoss the reason that they introduced a limit is that the higher you increase the value of org.apache.tomcat.util.htp.Parameters.MAX_COUNT the more vulnerable your are to CVE-2011-4858